# Switching between auto-inserts on the fly / by context

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Using emacs for multiple projects from legacy to current ones, I have to use multiple conventions, e.g. for comments or file headers. For example, I use this function to insert file headers for C++ files:

```
(defun mg-c-file-header()
  "Inserts a c/c++ file header"
  (if (boundp 'mg-auto-insert-style)
      (case mg-auto-insert-style
    (project-a
     (insert
      " * @file "(file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)"\n"
      " * \n"
      " * (c) 2000 - "( format-time-string "%Y" )" by someone\n"))
    (project-b
     (insert "/** another header*/\n"))
    (otherwise (message "Meh.")))))
```

I call this function in this context:

```
(setq auto-insert-alist
      '(
        (("\\.\\([C]\\|cc\\|cpp\\)\\'" . "C++ Program")
         nil
         ( mg-c-file-header )
         "// --- includes --- \n"
;; and do on....
```

I can set mg-auto-insert-style with M-x set-variable, that's ok. But I would like to automatically set the variable depending on the path of the file for the current buffer. So if I open a buffer or visit a new file in ~/projects/project-a, mg-auto-insert-style should be project-a.

This would work, but not perfectly:

```
(ede-cpp-root-project "project-a"
 :file "~/projects/project-a/trunk/src/Makefile"
 :local-variables (list
   (cons 'mg-auto-insert-style 'project-a )))
```

If I create a new file, mg-auto-insert-style is not bound when the auto-insertion is done. Later, there's no problem...

Do you have an idea?

cu, Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use auto-insert package, together with different templates to implement this. See [my config](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-auto-insert.el) as example (+ [templates](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/tree/master/auto-insert))

Answer (score 0):

See library [`header2.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/header2.el) and this Emacs wiki page: [Automatic File Headers](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutomaticFileHeaders).  You can configure the headers as you like.

Comment: Maybe I understand your suggestion wrong, but as I see it, it's already too late when headers2 or automatic file headers kick in...

Can headers2 create headers depending on, say, a config file in the same directory as the new file, or depending on the directory where the file is created?